# Notification intent is not working

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am trying to launch a new activity on click of notification. But problem is that notification intent is not working and when i click on notification it do nothing. Means its not launch new activity(Notificationjump.class). 
Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            notrify();
        }
    });
}

private void notrify() {
    int notificationid = 001;
    NotificationManager mNotifyManager =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);    
    Intent resultintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Notificationjump.class);
    resultintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  //  resultintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,1,resultintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify)
        .setContentTitle("Mynotification")
        .setContentText("Hello world");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
    mNotifyManager.notify(notificationid,mBuilder.build());
}
```

Here is my Notificationjump.class

```
package com.example.notification;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Notificationjump extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notifyjump);
    System.out.println("hellllllllllllo");
    finish();
}


}
```

Can somebody tell me why pending intent is not working?

Comment: What is your error? Does app crashes?

Comment: @AawazGyawali no error and .............app not crashes ......

Comment: Thats surprising...I don't know why this isn't working with you. But I tested the same, and its working on my side @DevendraDagur

Comment: Exactly! Code is fine. Is the NotificationJump really an activity??

Comment: @DevendraDagur fixed or not?

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra Sorry for late reply, No, it not fixed

Comment: @AawazGyawali Notification jump is really an activity ? yes it is.

Comment: Now it launching Notificationjump.class but it came back to MainActivity instantly, I don't know why........Previously I thought that it not launching Notificationjump activity but it doing it so fast that I am not able to recognize it ...that's why I ask this question.

Comment: It working now...........Actually problem is I used finish(); in my Notificationjump.class and that's why I am not able to stay in it. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: Can we do same thing without passing `Notificationjump.class` to Intent? Like calling `Intent resultintent = new Intent();` instead of `Intent resultintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EmploymentVerificationActivity.class);`@DevendraDagur

Answer (score 3):

> Means its not launch new activity(Notificationjump.class).

You are using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and this cause this, especially when you most likely have the same acivity posting notification on click, so it is front most while you tap notification.

> If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at
>   the top of the history stack.

So remove this flag if you want different behavior. See docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes

Comment: Its working now .....the problem was that I by mistake used finish(); in my Notificationjump.class thats why I am not able to stay in that class. And this action is so fast and I thought notification intent is not working. And in hurry I asked this question. And I am sorry for that.

Comment: That was actually my guess and main reason I asked to see this class code :)